# cx_freeze + PyQt5 + python

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I'm running in circles with a really strange thing happen. Basically I'm trying a simple window app with PyQt5+python3.3+cx_freeze4.3.2. The problem runs perfect calling the python:

```
python test.py
```

Now the second part the basic setup.py to the cx_freeze:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': 'atexit'
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('test.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='test',
      version='0.1',
      description='test',
      options=options,
      executables=executables
      )
```

build it:

```
python test.py build
```

The follow folder is created:

build/exe.win32-3.3:

```
/platforms
/imageformats
test.exe
icudt49.dll
icuin49.dll
icuuc49.dll
libGLESv2.dll
library.zip
PyQt5.QtCore.pyd
PyQt5.QtGui.pyd
PyQt5.QtWidgets.pyd
python33.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
sip.pyd
unicodedata.pyd
_bz2.pyd
```

Now running test.exe everything works fine as it should.

The problem comes when I copy the build folder to other PC. An error pops-up when I run the test.exe

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   QT platform plugin "windows".
>
> Available platform plugin are: minimal, offscreen, windows.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

According everything I read it's about dlls on plataforms/ the .exe don't find qwindow.dll inside. Why it's only happen in other PC (win7)?? The developement PC (win7) works fine. To debug it and to have sure that qwindow.dll used is the one inside on plataforms/ I rename the folder to plataformFOO/ and try run the test.exe and now same problem in dev PC, so, the dll is in correct folder, rename it back to plataforms/ and everything working fine. Why the hell is not working in others PCs if the OS is the same and the folder is a simple copy of the one on dev PC.

I google, read loads of stuffs but can't figure out the problem. If someone can help ;)

Comment: That's really odd - it says it can't load the "windows" platform plugin, but then lists it as one of the available plugins. I guess it must be failing to load for some reason. Maybe it relies on something else? Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) on the PC where your program works, and see if it's loading a DLL from somewhere else.

Comment: tested right now on PC where everything is working fine, qwindows.dll is loaded from platform/ inside of root folder (no others qwindows.dll is loading).. on other PC the dll is not loaded

Comment: By 'root folder', do you mean the build folder where cx_Freeze copied it? Is it loading any other DLLs from outside that folder?

Comment: Yes, I mean build folder created by cx_Freeze. Yes some others dlls from system32 (normal I think) and also load C:\Python33\DLLs\python3.dll and C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\libEGL.dll. Strange load the C:\Python33\DLLs\python3.dll because python33.dll is also loaded from build folder

Comment: I did other debug test. Removed PyQt on dev PC and the exe give me the same error that I got on Other PC. Install again the PyQt on dev PC and exe runs fine. The problem can be here: C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\libEGL.dll ? Only this dll is loaded directly from PyQt5 python folder. Btw, libEGL.dll is not listed on build folder

Comment: Ok, find the problem. just copy libEGL.dll from PyQt5 folder to build folder and it works fine now..

Comment: I guess qwindows.dll must load libEGL.dll. cx_Freeze checks DLLs for dependencies, but I don't think it checks DLLs in subfolders, so it wouldn't have found that. We'll have to fix that...

Comment: SO should let you answer your own question after a while, so the fix is clear for other people who read this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I'm running Anaconda 4.4.0 Python 2.7.13 using PyQt5 and cx_Freeze 5.0.1

Copy anaconda/library/plugin/platforms directory into the directory containing the .exe.

Run the executable and it should work

Comment: Tried that, no avail for me.